# does the app engine 200 index limit apply only to custom index (defined in index.yaml) or does it apply also to built-in index?

Tags: google-app-engine, indexing, google-cloud-datastore, quota

I could not find clear documentation regarding the limit on index. The official answer just say that there is a limit on the number of index (200).

I would interpret it as limiting any kind of index (either built in or not).

But I might be wrong and maybe some of you know the answer for sure

The reason I ask is that I plan to create Kinds on the fly and there is the possibility of having between 100 and 200 such kinds.

if the index limit apply only to custom index, I might be able to stay in the limit since I do not need much custom index

but if the limit apply to built-in index as well, since I would have 100-200 such kinds the built-in indexes would add up to more than 200

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Built-in indexes are not limited.

Limit is only for indexes listed in index.yaml file.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but where did you get the info from? did you make a test yourself or is it documented somewhere ?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/#Python_Quotas_and_limits - 20000 (built-in) index entries per entity.

Comment: the index entries per entity is not the same as the limit of the number of index (in https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas look for "Number of Indexes")